# Installing Flux.jl on Linux: NNlibCUDA fails to precompile

Tags: julia, flux.jl

While trying to install Flux I run into an error where it fails to precompile the **NNlibCUDA** library.

Running `] test NNlibCUDA` results in `LoadError: UndefVarError: upsample_linear_wcn! not defined`:

```
(@v1.7) pkg> test NNlibCUDA
     Testing NNlibCUDA
      Status `/tmp/jl_1psy2E/Project.toml`
  [052768ef] CUDA v3.10.1
  [f6369f11] ForwardDiff v0.10.30
  [872c559c] NNlib v0.8.6
  [a00861dc] NNlibCUDA v0.2.3
  [e88e6eb3] Zygote v0.6.40
  [37e2e46d] LinearAlgebra `@stdlib/LinearAlgebra`
  [9a3f8284] Random `@stdlib/Random`
  [10745b16] Statistics `@stdlib/Statistics`
  [8dfed614] Test `@stdlib/Test`
      Status `/tmp/jl_1psy2E/Manifest.toml`
  [621f4979] AbstractFFTs v1.1.0
  [79e6a3ab] Adapt v3.3.3
  [ab4f0b2a] BFloat16s v0.2.0
  [fa961155] CEnum v0.4.2
  [052768ef] CUDA v3.10.1
  [082447d4] ChainRules v1.35.1
  [d360d2e6] ChainRulesCore v1.15.0
  [9e997f8a] ChangesOfVariables v0.1.3
  [bbf7d656] CommonSubexpressions v0.3.0
  [34da2185] Compat v3.44.0
  [163ba53b] DiffResults v1.0.3
  [b552c78f] DiffRules v1.11.0
  [ffbed154] DocStringExtensions v0.8.6
  [e2ba6199] ExprTools v0.1.8
  [1a297f60] FillArrays v0.13.2
  [f6369f11] ForwardDiff v0.10.30
  [0c68f7d7] GPUArrays v8.3.2
  [61eb1bfa] GPUCompiler v0.15.2
  [7869d1d1] IRTools v0.4.6
  [3587e190] InverseFunctions v0.1.4
  [92d709cd] IrrationalConstants v0.1.1
  [692b3bcd] JLLWrappers v1.4.1
  [929cbde3] LLVM v4.13.0
  [2ab3a3ac] LogExpFunctions v0.3.15
  [1914dd2f] MacroTools v0.5.9
  [872c559c] NNlib v0.8.6
  [a00861dc] NNlibCUDA v0.2.3
  [77ba4419] NaNMath v1.0.0
  [21216c6a] Preferences v1.3.0
  [74087812] Random123 v1.5.0
  [e6cf234a] RandomNumbers v1.5.3
  [c1ae055f] RealDot v0.1.0
  [189a3867] Reexport v1.2.2
  [ae029012] Requires v1.3.0
  [276daf66] SpecialFunctions v2.1.5
  [90137ffa] StaticArrays v1.4.4
  [a759f4b9] TimerOutputs v0.5.19
  [e88e6eb3] Zygote v0.6.40
  [700de1a5] ZygoteRules v0.2.2
  [dad2f222] LLVMExtra_jll v0.0.16+0
  [efe28fd5] OpenSpecFun_jll v0.5.5+0
  [0dad84c5] ArgTools `@stdlib/ArgTools`
  [56f22d72] Artifacts `@stdlib/Artifacts`
  [2a0f44e3] Base64 `@stdlib/Base64`
  [ade2ca70] Dates `@stdlib/Dates`
  [8bb1440f] DelimitedFiles `@stdlib/DelimitedFiles`
  [8ba89e20] Distributed `@stdlib/Distributed`
  [f43a241f] Downloads `@stdlib/Downloads`
  [7b1f6079] FileWatching `@stdlib/FileWatching`
  [b77e0a4c] InteractiveUtils `@stdlib/InteractiveUtils`
  [4af54fe1] LazyArtifacts `@stdlib/LazyArtifacts`
  [b27032c2] LibCURL `@stdlib/LibCURL`
  [76f85450] LibGit2 `@stdlib/LibGit2`
  [8f399da3] Libdl `@stdlib/Libdl`
  [37e2e46d] LinearAlgebra `@stdlib/LinearAlgebra`
  [56ddb016] Logging `@stdlib/Logging`
  [d6f4376e] Markdown `@stdlib/Markdown`
  [a63ad114] Mmap `@stdlib/Mmap`
  [ca575930] NetworkOptions `@stdlib/NetworkOptions`
  [44cfe95a] Pkg `@stdlib/Pkg`
  [de0858da] Printf `@stdlib/Printf`
  [3fa0cd96] REPL `@stdlib/REPL`
  [9a3f8284] Random `@stdlib/Random`
  [ea8e919c] SHA `@stdlib/SHA`
  [9e88b42a] Serialization `@stdlib/Serialization`
  [1a1011a3] SharedArrays `@stdlib/SharedArrays`
  [6462fe0b] Sockets `@stdlib/Sockets`
  [2f01184e] SparseArrays `@stdlib/SparseArrays`
  [10745b16] Statistics `@stdlib/Statistics`
  [fa267f1f] TOML `@stdlib/TOML`
  [a4e569a6] Tar `@stdlib/Tar`
  [8dfed614] Test `@stdlib/Test`
  [cf7118a7] UUIDs `@stdlib/UUIDs`
  [4ec0a83e] Unicode `@stdlib/Unicode`
  [e66e0078] CompilerSupportLibraries_jll `@stdlib/CompilerSupportLibraries_jll`
  [deac9b47] LibCURL_jll `@stdlib/LibCURL_jll`
  [29816b5a] LibSSH2_jll `@stdlib/LibSSH2_jll`
  [c8ffd9c3] MbedTLS_jll `@stdlib/MbedTLS_jll`
  [14a3606d] MozillaCACerts_jll `@stdlib/MozillaCACerts_jll`
  [4536629a] OpenBLAS_jll `@stdlib/OpenBLAS_jll`
  [05823500] OpenLibm_jll `@stdlib/OpenLibm_jll`
  [83775a58] Zlib_jll `@stdlib/Zlib_jll`
  [8e850b90] libblastrampoline_jll `@stdlib/libblastrampoline_jll`
  [8e850ede] nghttp2_jll `@stdlib/nghttp2_jll`
  [3f19e933] p7zip_jll `@stdlib/p7zip_jll`
Precompiling project...
  ✗ NNlibCUDA
  0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 4 seconds (47 already precompiled)
  1 dependency errored. To see a full report either run `import Pkg; Pkg.precompile()` or load the package
     Testing Running tests...
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: upsample_linear_wcn! not defined
Stacktrace:
  [1] getproperty(x::Module, f::Symbol)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:35
  [2] top-level scope
    @ ~/.julia/packages/NNlibCUDA/vECff/src/upsample.jl:118
  [3] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:418
  [4] include(x::String)
    @ NNlibCUDA ~/.julia/packages/NNlibCUDA/vECff/src/NNlibCUDA.jl:1
  [5] top-level scope
    @ ~/.julia/packages/NNlibCUDA/vECff/src/NNlibCUDA.jl:9
  [6] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
  [7] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
  [8] top-level scope
    @ none:1
  [9] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [10] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [11] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/manman/.julia/packages/NNlibCUDA/vECff/src/upsample.jl:118
in expression starting at /home/manman/.julia/packages/NNlibCUDA/vECff/src/NNlibCUDA.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile NNlibCUDA [a00861dc-f156-4864-bf3c-e6376f28a68d] to /home/manman/.julia/compiled/v1.7/NNlibCUDA/jl_kwzmLD.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
 [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
 [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
 [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
 [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:997
 [7] include(fname::String)
   @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:451
 [8] top-level scope
   @ none:6
in expression starting at /home/manman/.julia/packages/NNlibCUDA/vECff/test/runtests.jl:4
ERROR: Package NNlibCUDA errored during testing
```

I am running **Julia 1.7.3** on **Pop!_OS 22.04** with a **GTX 1050Ti Mobile**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this issue. I found that running `] update` fixed it.